# Why a bar button item on a NavigationViewController won't trigger an IBAction

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I have a pretty basic app I am working on that uses a navigation view controller system. One of my view is a table view that I added a bar button to in the story board. This bar button is just a basic add button for adding a new item to the table view. I identified the segue for use in my prepare for segue method and then I created an IBAction for the button as well.

The segue pushes to my next view just fine and passed my desired object, but the action never triggered.  I ended up having to put the code for the IBAction in my prepare for segue method to get it to work.

I'm just wondering why IBAction was never triggered.

Comment: Do you have a segue in IB from the UIBarButtonItem to the new view controller?

Comment: Yes, the UIBarButtonItem is in the TableViewController and I connected to the next view and have labeled the segue.

Comment: This is impossible to answer, post code or upload the project somewhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) remove the  `segueNamedFoo` you have created from the button to the destination view controller

2) create a manual `segueNamedFoo` push segue by CTRL-dragging from the leftmost small icon at the base of the origin view controller to the destination view controller

3) in your `- (IBAction)doStuffBeforeSegue:(id)sender` method which you have connected to your button perform the tasks which you want and then call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueNamedFoo"]`

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I ended up doing and it work like a charm.

Comment: No problem - an up vote would be much appreciated if you have a moment.  Cheers.